# Give an element different colors with `ng-repeat`

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

#### HTML logic vs Javascript logic

I want to do something very simple. Based on the priority description, **I want to give different colors to the td**.

This HTML is generated dynamically based on the tickets. Now let's say I have 10 types of descriptions the html will start to get messy. Is there a better way or it's ok to do this?

```
 <tr ng-repeat="ticket in tickets">
                        
   <td class="color-SOMETHING">{{ticket.TICKET_PRIORITY_DESCRIPTION}}</td>

  <tr>
```

Comment: Is the priority description from a fixed set of possible values?

Comment: Yes. they are fetched from the database. It's stuff like: High,Normal,Low,Very low, etc..

Comment: CSS can't detect text so classes are probably your only option.

Answer (score 8):

Try using the priority as class:

```
<tr ng-repeat="ticket in tickets">
    <td class="color-{{ticket.TICKET_PRIORITY_DESCRIPTION}}">{{ticket.TICKET_PRIORITY_DESCRIPTION}}</td>
</tr>
```

Then, in your css add this:

```
.color-high {
   background-color: red;
}

.color-low {
   background-color: green;
}

.color-normal {
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

Etc., one for each priority you have.

Answer (score 1):

Apply conditional classes based on the ticket property like this

```
<tr ng-repeat="ticket in tickets">

   <td class="color-SOMETHING" ng-class="{'redColor': ticket.TICKET_PRIORITY_DESCRIPTION=='high', 'yelloColor': ticket.TICKET_PRIORITY_DESCRIPTION=='medium', 'blueColor': ticket.TICKET_PRIORITY_DESCRIPTION=='low'}">{{ticket.TICKET_PRIORITY_DESCRIPTION}}</td>

  <tr>
```

CSS

```
.redColor {
  background-color: red;
}
.yelloColor {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.blueColor {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: This is not wrong. but more conditions make the template messier.

Comment: yeah i liked the other answer too :) i wonder why i didnt think of it when i have actually used something like this many times in my code ! :(